# How to create installer with separate unistallers for multiple components

Tags: windows, installation

We have an application consisting of multiple components: **main** app (installed in program files) and multiple **datasets** (located in AppData). In the future there will be available (also) individual updates for one of components. What I want is to create **one** installer for all components, but create multiple uninstallers for components accessible from Programs and Functions. I've looked at Inno Setup, but I think it doesn't support this. Also tried NSIS, but it looks much difficult to use.

Comment: That's not how MSI works.  Writing custom non-MSI based uninstallers is a poor substitute for just writing an installer for each dataset.  You can chain them.

Comment: That sounds good. Is there any tool for chaining multiple installers to one file?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be just as well (or better?) to make it all one install/uninstall program. And it works by noticing which features are present? If none then your screen consists of check boxes with what you want and don't want, then upon running it again later you would uncheck what you want to remove, etc.

Comment: When an update for any of components is available, I don't want to confuse user with checkboxes. After update installation confirmation it should uninstall older and install newer version without user interaction.